# what is the actual difference between gluortho2d and glViewport

Tags: opengl

I made a window sized `800x600`. I called

```
gluOrtho2D(-400,400,-300,300);
glViewport(400,300,400,300);
```

and I drew a line from `(-100,-100)` to `(100,100)`. I think I should see a line from `(0,0)` to `(100,100)`, but I am getting the whole line. Why is this?

Answer (score 10):

In theory, `glViewport` [doesn't cause any clipping (see section 10)](http://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/). Normally, all drawing is clipped to the window. Since you have asked OpenGL to draw into a region of your window, you will need to also tell OpenGL to clip coordinates outside this viewport. For that, you will need `glScissor`. However, some implementations do clip their drawing to the viewport (see my comment for details).

In addition, your math is wrong. Your projection matrix is 800 units wide by 600 units tall, centered at (0, 0). This is then mapped to a portion of the window that is 400 pixels wide by 300 pixels tall, in the upper-right corner of the window.

If you draw a line from (-100, -100) to (100, 100), it will extend across only a small part of your viewing frustrum. The frustrum is sized to fit in the viewport.

In the image, the blue box is the window, and the red box represents the viewport. The black line should be the line that you drew.

[An image describing what the paragraph says. http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/6541/opengl.png](http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/6541/opengl.png)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Yep. This stuff can be tricky at first. Eventually, you'll find it to be second nature.

Comment: I've been trying to prove glViewport doesn't do any clipping but every time I try I see it clip. Example, draw a triangle from (0, 3), (3, -3), (-3, 3). See a clipped triangle. Set the glViewport(windowWidth / 4, windowHeight, windowWidth / 2, windowHeigth / 2); See effectively the same clipped triangle in the center of the display. If glViewport was not doing any clipping I'd expect to see more of the triangle but I don't. What am I not getting?

Comment: You got me, I should have tested before I posted. At least in WebGL in Chrome on MacOS 10.7, the viewport that you set is also used to clip fragments. But that is not guaranteed behavior. See my edits at the top of the answer.

Comment: +1 for the comment about `glScissor`. I've been searching for information on it for a while. Everyone says "glScissor defines a scissor box."

Answer (score 0):

glViewport describes the area of your window which will be drawn by OpenGL.
glOrtho or gluOrtho2D define a unit system (OpenGL units) which fit into that (via glViewport defined) area.
So your line will be drawn within the Viewport from -100,-100 to 100,100